# Test-Path and Remove-Item Not Working for File that Exists When Called from Other Application

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a powershell script that checks a few folders on the network for a given file, and deletes it using specific credentials it if it is found.

When I put this script on the server and run it from a command line, it works fine.

When I run it from a separate batch file, it works fine.

When I run it from an MVC app on the same server, using System.Management.Automation.Powershell, the script runs but the "Test-Path" command says the file does not exist, and the "Remove-Item" command does not remove the file, even if the "Test-Path" condition is removed.

I have checked, and the path and file name are correct when it's being called by the MVC app, but for some reason the script does not recognize it.

Any idea why this is the case?

Here's the script (I know this isn't the best way to store password, it's not a production script yet):

```
$username = 'domain\del'
$password = '*******'

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
$networkPath = "\\network\files\";
[string[]]$folders = "Folder1", "Folder2", "Folder3"
$param = $Args[0];

if($param)
{
    for($i=0; $i -lt $folders.Length; $i++)
    {
        $path = $networkPath + $folders[$i] + "\" + $param; 
        if ($path | Test-Path)
        {
            Remove-Item $path -Credential $credentail -force
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm executing it from the MVC app:

```
string file = (string)filename;
string root = Server.MapPath("~");
string script = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DeleteScannerImageScriptName"];
PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create();
shell.AddScript(root + script + " " + file);
Collection<PSObject> results = shell.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the credentials/user session isn't being used. From [Test-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-5.1#parameters) and [Remove-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-5.1#parameters) documentation:

**Parameter:**

```
-Credential
```

> Note:
>
> This parameter is not supported by any providers installed with
>   PowerShell. To impersonate another user, or elevate your credentials
>   when running this cmdlet, use `Invoke-Command`.

If you need to run under different credentials, you will need to wrap it in an [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-5.1) or use impersonation.

Comment: Ah, that clarifies why it wasn't working properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what's wrong with this process but I instead decided to use impersonation in C# directly and it is working.

[WindowsImpersonationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)